# Backpressure via BufferBlock not working. (C# TPL Dataflow)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

Typical situation: **Fast producer, slow consumer, need to slow producer down**.
Sample code that doesn't work as I expected (explained below):

```cs
//  I assumed this block will behave like BlockingCollection, but it doesn't 
var bb = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions {
    BoundedCapacity = 3, // looks like this does nothing
});

// fast producer
int dataSource = -1;
var producer = Task.Run(() => {
    while (dataSource < 10) {
        var message = ++dataSource;
        bb.Post(message);
        Console.WriteLine($"Posted: {message}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Calling .Complete() on buffer block");
    bb.Complete();
});

// slow consumer
var ab = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine($"Received: {i}");
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2,
});

bb.LinkTo(ab);

ab.Completion.Wait();
```

**How I thought this code would work, but it doesn't:**

- `BufferBlock` `bb` is the blocking queue with capacity of 3. Once capacity reached, producer should not be able to `.Post()` to it, until there's a vacant slot.

  - Doesn't work like that. `bb` seems to happily accept any number of messages.
- `producer` is a task that quickly Posts messages. Once all messages have been posted, the call to `bb.Complete()` should propagate through the pipeline and signal shutdown once all messages have been processed. Hence waiting `ab.Completion.Wait();` at the end.

  - Doesn't work either. As soon as `.Complete()` is called, action block `ab` won't receive any more messages.

Can be done with a `BlockingCollection`, which I thought in TPL Dataflow (TDF) world `BufferBlock` was the equivalent of. I guess I'm misunderstanding how backpressure is supposed to work in TPL Dataflow.

**So where's the catch? How to run this pipeline, not allowing more than 3 messages in the buffer `bb`, and wait for its completion?**

PS: I found this gist (https://gist.github.com/mnadel/df2ec09fe7eae9ba8938) where it's suggested to maintain a semaphore to block writing to `BufferBlock`. I thought this was "built-in".

**Update after accepting an answer:**

## Updates after accepting the answer:

#### If you're looking at this question, you need to remember that `ActionBlock` also has its own input buffer.

That's for one. Then you also need to realize, that because all blocks have their own input buffers you don't need the `BufferBlock` for what you might think its name implied. A `BufferBlock` is more like a utility block for more complex architectures or like a balance loading block. But it's not a backpressure buffer.

#### Completion propagation needs to be dfined at link level explicitly.

When calling `.LinkTo()` need to explicitly pass `new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true}` as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Have tried to use [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.sendasync?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `Post`? It block until there is a free space

Comment: Yeah what you want is `await someBlock.SendAsync(item)` that will wait for a free space in blocks queue. `Post` will just return false when it can't insert an item.

Comment: You should post your update as an answer and accept it, as it is the real solution (I was going to post exactly what you said). I would upvote it if you did.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the suggestion, was a bit lazy. Btw, if you have a better sample than what I've posted now, please post it here, I'd gladly change the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the guidance from JSteward's answer, I came up with the following code.
It produces (reads etc.) new items concurrently with processing said items, maintaining a read-ahead buffer.
The completion signal is sent to the head of the chain when the "producer" has no more items.
The program also awaits the completion of the whole chain before terminating.

```cs
static async Task Main() {

    string Time() => $"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff}";

    // the buffer is added to the chain just for demonstration purposes
    // the chain would work fine using just the built-in input buffer
    // of the `action` block.
    var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>(new DataflowBlockOptions {BoundedCapacity = 3});

    var action = new ActionBlock<int>(async i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Time()}]: Processing: {i}");
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2, BoundedCapacity = 2});

    // it's necessary to set `PropagateCompletion` property
    buffer.LinkTo(action, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});

    //Producer
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Time()}]: Ready to send: {i}");
        await buffer.SendAsync(i);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{Time()}]: Sent: {i}");
    }

    // we call `.Complete()` on the head of the chain and it's propagated forward
    buffer.Complete(); 

    await action.Completion;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To introduce back pressure you need use `SendAsync` when you send items into the block. This allows your producer to wait for the block to be ready for the item. Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 3
        };
        var block = new ActionBlock<int>(async i =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }, options);

        //Producer
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
        {
            await block.SendAsync(i);
        }

        block.Complete();
        await block.Completion;
    }
}
```

If you change this to use `Post` and print the result of the `Post` you'll see that many items fail to be passed to the block:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 1
        };
        var block = new ActionBlock<int>(async i =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }, options);

        //Producer
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
        {
            var result = block.Post(i);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        block.Complete();
        await block.Completion;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
0
```